# Google Play Services Plugin to Unity Have some Errors

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, google-play-services

I have downloaded Google Play Services Plugin with github and 
Export package in Unity (Version 4.3.4f1).
but I can see 3 errors which are:

```
Assets/GooglePlayGames/Platforms/Android/AndroidRtmpClient.cs(491,62): error CS1502: The best overloaded method match for `GooglePlayGames.BasicApi.Multiplayer.Participant.Participant(string, string, GooglePlayGames.BasicApi.Multiplayer.Participant.ParticipantStatus, GooglePlayGames.BasicApi.Multiplayer.Player, bool)' has some invalid arguments

Assets/GooglePlayGames/Platforms/Android/AndroidRtmpClient.cs(491,62): error CS1503: Argument `#4' cannot convert `object' expression to type `GooglePlayGames.BasicApi.Multiplayer.Player'

Assets/GooglePlayGames/Platforms/Android/AndroidRtmpClient.cs(491,54): error CS1729: The type `Player' does not     contain a constructor that takes `2' arguments
```

Please help me.

Comment: Have you considered looking at the source code and fixing the difference? https://github.com/playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity/tree/master/source/PluginDev/Assets/GooglePlayGames/Platforms/Android

Comment: Also, do you have any source code that you are using in your project that used the Play service? If so they could you post that as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my case this was happening because I had Player class defined both in my code and in Google Play Games unity package. When I renamed my class everything worked as expected.

Comment: I have the same problem and changed my custom class name.

Answer (score 2):

This happens because of another Player class, simply check where the error is and change Player to GooglePlayGames.BasicApi.Multiplayer.Player (this means that the script will get the Player class from google play games) on the errors of google play games scripts.

Comment: This solution is preferable if you are adding Google Play Games to an existing/legacy project in my opinion